# Incorporating a log4net wrapper class in a C#.NET project following MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, log4net

I've created a log4net wrapper class for my project team to use so we can all log from the same instance of log4net in our project. We're unsure what section this could come under i.e. Controller, one suggestion was to create a separate folder altogether for "Helper" classes.

Is there an industry standard to follow for this that we could use?

Comment: Your question is arguably subjec to opinion. [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak to an 'industry standard' but for our application, putting the logging at the lowest level has worked best for us.  We created our own class that wraps the 3rd party functionality in a one of our libraries referenced by nearly all others.  Then we implemented our own methods to simplify and standardize logging in our app.  This approach makes it possible to use logging anywhere without significant project changes.  You'd just have to add static method calls where you need to log something.

Comment: Don't feed the pigeons.  _[Stance on answering “bad” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281793/stance-on-answering-bad-questions)_ and _[Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)_

Answer (score 0):

No there's no industrial standard for such things. Nevertheless, instead of creating another wrapper for log4net consider using the existing [one](https://github.com/net-commons/common-logging). Then simply register it in the DI of your choice and inject it via constructor.

Comment: Don't feed the pigeons.  _[Stance on answering “bad” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281793/stance-on-answering-bad-questions)_ and _[Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)_